# Why exactly eraseCredentials is needed/recommended?

Tags: symfony

In Symfony2, in UserInterface is a method named "eraseCredentials" it is described in documentation as:

> Removes sensitive data from the user.
>
> This is important if, at any given point, sensitive information like the plain-text password is stored on this object.

But let's say we have a registration form:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($user, array(
        'data_class' => 'Yoda\UserBundle\Entity\User',
    ))
    ->add('username', 'text')
    ->add('email', 'text')
    ->add('password', 'repeated', array(
          'type' => 'password',
         ))
    ->getForm()
;

$form->handleRequest($request);
if ($form->isValid()) {

    $user = $form->getData();
    $user->setPassword($this->encodePassword($user, $user->getPassword()));

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($user);
    $em->flush();
}
```

It seems that user plain password is being replaced instantly. Are the internals of Symfony2 authentication system an issue when using a default login mechanism (but if yes - why Symfony2 cannot deal with it internally?)? Can someone explain, how not using "eraseCredentials" makes/can make a security issue?

**Added:**
I will also add, that I kind of understand the THEORETICAL impurity, with two kinds of information being stored in the same variable (encoded and plain password)... but if plain password will be always INSTANTLY encoded (which is easy to check), this seems to be a virtual problem. Am I wrong?

**Added 2:**
Isn't (theoretically) introducing the second variable with plain password INCREASING the risk - because in some situations eraseCredentials could be not invoked (eg. https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/13287 ) ?? O_o

Answer (score 1):

I could think of scenario when you are returning hydrated user entity  using ajax, you would probably want to temporary remove sensitive data like plain password, bank account etc. from response.